# Hyperlink custom link_location formula

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I want to make custom link_location formula

```
= HYPERLINK("file:///C:\Users\PC\Desktop\File01.pdf", B1)
```

I have a column B where File01, File02,...... is listed.

I want to create hyperlink to locate the file on my Hard-disk with the same name as seen in above hyperlink.

How to Create a common hyperlink in column C where I don't have to change the file name manually. It will just take the value of Column B.

```
= HYPERLINK("file:///C:\Users\PC\Desktop\B1.pdf", B1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

=HYPERLINK("file:///C:\Users\PC\Desktop\" & B1 & ".pdf", B1)